# Angular StaticInjectorErrors for Location, LocationStrategy and PlatformLocation

Tags: angular, angular5

I created a generalized npm module that can be used by any angular 5 app . In the shared module, there's a global service that injects Location. The global service looks like this:

global.service.ts

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
ixport {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
  location:Location;
  constructor(location: Location) {
   ...
}
```

And my shared module (shared.module.ts)

```
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ]
})

export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: [
            Location,
            { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: 
            PathLocationStrategy },
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

And here's my index.ts file which exports the module and services

```
export {SharedModule} from './shared.module';
export {GlobalService} from './src/services/global.service';
```

Now what i'm trying to do is import this service into my app.module.ts file and use it in some components on that module.  My app.module.ts looks like this:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { SharedModule } from '../../node_modules/shared/shared.module'; 
import { GlobalService } from '../../node_modules/shared/src/services/global.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
],
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ...
],
  providers: [GlobalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
  export class AppModule {

}
```

When I add it to my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalService } from '../../src/services/global.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(globalService:GlobalService){
  }
}
```

I get a staticInjectorError:no provider for Location. So I import Location add the Location provider inside of the shared module, then i get staticInjectorError:no provider for LocationStrategy so I do the same for LocationStrategy and PathLocationStrategy and add {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass:PathLocationStrategy} to my providers. Then I get a staticInjectorError:no provider for PlatformLocation. I'm pretty much out of solutions at this point.

What's the correct way of handling this case of importing services with dependencies into another module?

FYI. I was successfully able to add a service without dependencies from shared.module to app.module

Answer (score 0):

There are certain [recommendations from Angular](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-kinds-of-modules-should-i-have-and-how-should-i-use-them) on how you should organize your modules.

Ideally [Singleton Services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service) should be part of a `Core Module`

The `Pipes`, `Directives` and other common `Components` can be part of a [`Shared Module`](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules).

In this particular case, your service depends upon some of the providers from the `CommonModule`. You should add `CommonModule` to the `exports` of the `NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ],
    providers : [ 
      GlobalService
    ],
    exports: [
      CommonModule
    ]
})
```

This should do the trick.